# Linux command to find text in most recent file matching name pattern

Tags: linux, command-line, find, grep

I have a directory of files like so:

```
parent
    /dir1
        file1
        file2
        other
        something
        name_pattern.o23409284
        name_pattern.o29203429
        name_pattern.o39208235
    /dir2
    ...
```

I want to run a command that will look in the newest name_pattern.o* file for a line beginning with:

```
***END
```

So it seems easy enough to do

```
grep -c '***END' name_pattern.o*
```

but I want to only look at the most recent file and ignore all others.  So I think I need some kind of `find` command that will choose the newest file.  I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -e 'print( ( sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } @ARGV )[0], "\n");' name_pattern.o*
```

This sorts them by last-modification-time. Swap the $a and $b to have it give oldest instead. There are also modification flags to "find" but I find it difficult to have find do comparative-within-a-directory operations...

If you need it in one-line:

```
grep '***END' `perl -e 'print( ( sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } @ARGV )[0], "\n");' name_pattern.o*`
```

Comment: with so many things in one line, i'd really break it up and do some error checking (i.e. are there 0 files), but theoretically, yes

Comment: Sorry I deleted that comment because the formatting was all weird.  Basically, I want to just put that grep in an if statement to see if it found that line.  But I could just store the value in a variable and check that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Even the following can also do it.

```
ls -t | head -n1 name_pattern.o*
```

this will select the files that start with the given pattern, latest timestamp comes first, and take only the first file. So finally do this,

```
grep -c '***END' `ls -t | head -n1 name_pattern.o*`
```